# Get Bluetooth paired devices RSSI

Tags: android, bluetooth

I developing an app that relies on bluetooth signal strength for already paired devices. I retrieving the set of bonded devices using getBondedDevices from BluetoothAdapter.

What I'd like to know is how can I get the RSSI for those specific devices?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A paired device != a transmitting device in range. For RSSI your device needs to be receiving something.

Comment: It's an Android Wear device, so I believe it have a constant connection to the phone, how should I read the RSSI in that scenario?.